# PDO connection with database failing on certificate vertification

Tags: php, ubuntu, ssl, pdo

I've been running a mysql database on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.
Everything is working correctly except when I try to implement SSL following these tutorials:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-ssl-tls-for-mysql-on-ubuntu-16-04
https://www.acunetix.com/blog/articles/securing-mysql-server-ubuntu-16-04-lts-configuring-mysql-securely-part-3/

the connection fails. I've tried to implement it using both PDO and a normal MYSQLI connection but it keeps failing on the certificate verification.

I am running PHP 7.1.8 with the mysqlnd transporter.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>SSL Connection test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php
    phpinfo();
    $servername = "****";
    $username = "****";
    $password = "****";
    $dbname = "****";

    $options = array(
      PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_KEY => 'client-key.pem',
      PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CERT => 'client-cert.pem',
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => 'ca.pem',
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT => true,
    );

    try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;port=3306;dbname=$dbname;", $username, $password, $options);
        // set the PDO error mode to exception
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        echo "Connected successfully";
            var_dump($conn->query("SHOW STATUS LIKE 'Ssl_cipher';")->fetchAll());
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
        {
        echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }

    ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is the code I am using at the moment to test the functionality.
Whenever I make `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT` false the connection succeeds. If `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT` is true the connection fails.

Error messages on failure:

> Connection failed: SQLSTATE[HY000][2002]

Message on connection:

> Connected successfullyarray(1) { [0]=> array(4) { ["Variable_name"]=> string(10) "Ssl_cipher" [0]=> string(10) "Ssl_cipher" ["Value"]=> string(18) "DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA" [1]=> string(18) "DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA" } }

The certificates have been checked through the following code:

```
openssl verify -CAfile ca.pem server-cert.pem client-cert.pem
```

This returns OK for both files.

I've been trying to fix this for the last couple of hours but I can't seem to figure out the problem.

Please help me fix this problem.

Edit: All the files (`client-key.pem`, `client-cert.pem`, `ca.pem`) have been tested with `is_readable` and are readable.

Answer (score 1):

As you may know, in your Windows Server IIS PHP config, you need to set an openssl.cafile directive, providing the path to a Certificate Authority (CA) file. This is not necessary on Linux, where the system default is used. MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA needs this path on Windows, and may be omitted on Linux.

To add this logic into your PDO test script, add an extra variable with your OS information and change the MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA line:

```
$OS = ( strtoupper( substr( PHP_OS, 0, 3 ) ) === 'WIN' );
PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => $OS ? 'c:/path/to/cacert.pem' : '',
```

Your $options array becomes:

```
$OS = ( strtoupper( substr( PHP_OS, 0, 3 ) ) === 'WIN' );

$options = array(
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8',
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => $OS ? 'c:/path/to/cacert.pem' : '',
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT => false,
);
```

f `$OS === true (e.g $OS === 'WIN')` use `c:/path/to/cacert.pem` as PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA file path, else we’re on Linux and omit the path. This way you are sure you can use this PHP code cross-platform on both Windows Server and Linux!

Secure MySQL connection with WordPress

In WordPress you can use the Secure DB Connection plugin to set up and configure an SSL connection to your MySQL database. Don’t forget to set REQUIRE SSL in your database privileges.

Comment: Hello! The code works but this is the same as I had before. The verification still does not work whenever `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT` is false the connection functions but the problem is exactly that. The code worked before implementing the windows part. I'm also not using Windows Server, the mysql server is hosted on Ubuntu. I'm simply testing it on a normal Win10 computer.